# How to loop through each element in a div using Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to loop through all the elements in a div. How can I do it?

Till now I have tried like below but its not working. I expect it has to print all the elements in the container_class but its printing like this "[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (d3434gfe-d431-4e51-e6rt-a3asewc7806f)] -> xpath: id("divs_container_class")]]"

I want to print all the elements, what am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="container_class" id="container_id">
    <div id="1" class="1 class"></div>
    <div id="2" class="2 class"></div>
    <div id="3" class="3 class"></div>
    <div id="4" class="4 class"></div>
</div>
```

Java(Selenium):

```
List<WebElement> elementsxpath = driver.findElements(By.xpath("id(\"divs_container_class\")"));
for(int i=0; i<elementsxpath .size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(elementsxpath);
}
```

Comment: What exactly shall the code print? Your code works fine - it prints the WebElement object itself, which is just a kind of handle to the element in a remote web browser. Do you want to print its HTML code? Or its text body?

Comment: Oh, and by the way - your XPath seems to be invalid, at least in your example here. You should use an XPath matching all child elements, not the parent element (something with `/div` or `/*` at the end)

Comment: I want to loop through all the elements in the container_class and to find the elements background color. So, if any of the elements color is blue then click it.

Comment: @SarabuSandeep Use getCssValue("background-color").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the html body you posted is valid you can try with the below code.

```
 List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#container_id > div"));
 for (WebElement element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.getText());  
 }
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to use a CSS selector, `#container_id > div`. You can get the inner DIVs in a single locator instead of having to scrape the page twice. Remove the first line and replace the second line with `List<WebElement> links = 
 driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#container_id > div"));`

Comment: @JeffC Thanks. I know that but i post the two step code just to understand the hierarchical steps to get specific element.